# AWS DocumentDb queries running slow compared to Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-documentdb

I have a mongo collection containing about 1 000 000 documents. The collection has an index (among other indexes) on the 'product_type' field. There are about 70 000 items of product_type 'foo'. When I execute the query (see below) on my local development machine, the query takes about 1 second. When I execute the exact same query on AWS DocumentDb (with the same size collection and indexes, and similar computing power), the query can take anywhere from 60 s to 1500 s (depending on the product_type specified). I am executing the query through a python flask application (running on an EC2 instance in the same geographic region). The query also performs a projection to only return the document ids and one other property. It seems to be the case across the board that my queries are a lot slower on DocumentDb. Additional info: The server instance is located behind a bastion server and the flask application is running on an Apache server (installed on the EC2 instance). Everything is running inside a VPC. It does seem that queries are slower across the board (not only this query). Can anything give me some advice on what might be the cause of the bottleneck?

The query:

```
    query = {
        'properties.property1': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property2': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property3': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property4': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property5': {'$ne': None},
        'product_ids': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property6': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property7': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property8': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property9': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property10': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property11': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property12': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property13': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property14': {'$ne': None},
        'product_type': {'$regex': '^foo$', '$options': 'i'},
        'date': {'$ne': None},
        'status': 'ENABLED',
        'properties': {'$ne': None},
        'properties.property15': {'$ne': True}
    }
```

Things that I have tried to speed up the query (without much success):
Removed the regex and set the product_type directly as 'foo'
Perform the query in batches using 'skip' and 'limit'
Tried using different indexes ('product_type') was the best one I could find so far.
Tried different variants of the query (removing different items from the query)

Comment: Have you tried changing the instance type to one with more RAM? You can use the unofficial [DocumentDB sizing calculator](https://sizing.cloudnativedb.com/) to estimate the right instance size for your particular workload.

Comment: have you tried getting the query plan? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/user_diagnostics.html#user_diagnostics-query_plan

Comment: this can be due to many reasons such as the query is not optimized for DocumentDB, the instance size is not matching your requirement, etc.

I would like you to try a couple of things.
Go to cloud watch and inspect the resource usage 
Follow the below and do some query optimization

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/user_diagnostics.html#user_diagnostics-query_plan

Answer (score 1):

There are some [functional differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.regex-indexing) regarding Amazon DocumentDB, one of them is that for `$regex` you have to explicitly hint the index in order to use it.
Also, I see you're using `$ne`, there is no index support currently, you might have to modify the query to an equality filter or maybe use a comparison operator instead. As stated in the MongoDB documentation as well:

> The inequality operator
> $ne
> is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a
> $ne
> query with an index may perform no better than a
> $ne
> query that must scan all documents in a collection.